# How to get feedback over multiple solutions of a particular exercise of a book?

Tags: discussion, support, asking-questions

I am self studying C++ from [Robert Lafore's OOP in C++](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0672323087). I am solving the exercise questions of chapter-3 loop and decisions. For the first question(say X) I've written three different codes using different approaches(y1, y2 nd y3). I want to get feedback over my codes like a teacher is supposed to give feedback to his student. I want to get feedback over each code individually and then want to know which solution is overall better or more efficient.

The problem is how do I ask it so as it'd fit the Q&A format of SE. I've following options in mind:

- Post all the three codes y1, y2 and y3 in one question and ask -- For sure everything would mud up.
- Ask four different questions. First three for y1, y2 and y3's individual feedback and fourth one giving links to all three and asking which approach is best.

I think the second option is ok but if there is anything I need to keep in mind or any guidlines? E.g. should I first disclose at the beginning of each question that it is a part of four similar questions?

---

P.S: I've solved the first question of chapter 3:

> Assume that you want to generate a table of multiples of any given number. Write a program that allows the user to enter the number and then generates the table, formatting it
>   into 10 columns and 20 lines. Interaction with the program should look like this (only the
>   first three lines are shown):

```
    Enter a number: 7
    7     14     21     28     35     42     49     56     63     70
   77     84     91     98    105    112    119    126    133    140
  147    154    161    168    175    182    189    196    203    210
```

I've already uploaded the solutions on [my github account](https://github.com/AnupamKhosla/Anupam_Solutions/tree/master/Solutions/My_Robert-Lafore_Sol/Ch3_Loops%26Decision/Ex1) -- if you want to see them.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

These are very short solutions to the same problem.  Just ask one question with a [comparative-review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/comparative-review) tag, containing the description of the exercise, followed by three separate code blocks.  Please also mention what you think are the pros and cons of each of your solutions.

Comment: Thanks for your feedback. I've asked the question [link](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/q/122058/71410). It has become a large question though.

Comment: @user31782 Large questions aren't a problem at Code Review as long as they're written clearly.